# How do I return multiple database rows in an asmx web service

Tags: asp.net, asmx

I can return a single value in my webservice, but I can't figure out how to return multiple rows. I have an ILIST collection of the data from my database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method of your web service returns arrays of objects, that should do the trick.
So basically you just have to convert that IList to an array and, depending on what type of objects you have in the IList, fill some standard objects with the data to be returned.

Comment: I was missing the cast from ILIST to LIST. -Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create a class that can hold all the rows, then return that class

Answer (score 0):

Assuming u want multiple data to pass to web service and get resultant records in ur table.
 this example will help u to understand.

```
        function searchbudget() {
        var v1= $("#BEMISCODE").val();
        var v2= $("#From_Year").val();
        var v3= $("#To_Year").val();

        var table = $("#tblschoolinfo");

        var d = [];
        d.push(bemiscode);
        d.push(fromyear);
        d.push(toyear);

        var jsnDta = JSON.stringify({ data: d });

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "wbservices/GetBudgetByYearOrBemiscode.asmx/GetCompleteBudgetByBemiscodeOrYear",
            data: jsnDta,
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (r) {

                var rtnData = r.d; //all returned data...
                var respDta = [];
                $.map(rtnData, function (item, index) {
                    var j = [
                        item.status,
                        item.msg,
                    ];
                    respDta.push(j);

                });
                $.each(respDta, function (key, value) {
                    var status = value[0];
                    var msg = value[1];

                    if (status == true) {

                        table.html(msg);

                    } else {

                        var eMsg = '<div style="color:white;background:#FF4040" ><i style="margin-left:5px" class="fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i>"' + msg + '"</div>';
                        table.html(eMsg);

                    }

                }); //1st out loop ends here...


            },
            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                //  $("#responseMovDetails").html(jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);
                alert("error while loading Records of Requests" + jqXHR + textStatus + errorThrown);

            }

        });
    }
```